# Lisp Def Method Structure

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

```
(defmethod update :before ((a AGENT) (e UPDATE))
  (when (null (timestamps a))
    (push 0 (pls a))
    (push 0 (fitnesses a)))
  (push (timestamp e) (timestamps a))
  (push (price e) (revalprices a))
  (preprocess a e)
  (format T ":BEFORE completed for agent  ̃A and event  ̃A ̃%" a e))
```

The above method came from a book and I wanted to inquire about what is the difference between `update` and `:before`. From my understanding from defining methods in CLOS Lisp, the `update` is the name of the method, but what does `:before` do?

Lastly what does the last line do? `(format T ":BEFORE completed for agent  ̃A and event  ̃A ̃%" a e))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is the definition of a `:before` auxiliary method. When the method `update` is called with arguments that satisfy the types `agent` and `update`, this piece of code will run before the main method body. It's also possible to define `:after` and `:around` auxiliaries. Have a look at [this PCL chapter](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) for more information.

As to the `format` string, I assume that's mistranscribed. The form you've got there will just issue a warning that you're passing it too many format arguments. I think what's meant is

```
(format t ":BEFORE completed for agent ~a and event ~a~%" a e)
```

which will print `":BEFORE completed for agent "` followed by the value of `a`, followed by `" and event "` followed by the value of `e`, followed by a newline, to the stream `*standard-output*`. For more information on CL's `format` directives, take a look at [this other PCL chapter](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html), and possibly also [this section of the CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm)